# css background-color won't show up in Chrome browser behind an image

Tags: html, css

the following code works fine in Dreamweaver and in the FireFox browser, but the "background-color" value from the css file does not show up behind the image in the Chrome browser.  I'm trying to get it to show up.  I'm using crazy colors so that I can see things clearly for testing.

```css
.center2
{
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding:0px;
  //background-color:#1F3;
  background-color:#6F3;
}

div.main3
{
  text-align:center;
  width:950px;
  background-color:#39F;
  border-color:#F00;
  border-width:thin;
  border-style:none;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="Aquamarine">
  <div class="main3">
    <div class="center2">
      <h1>My Drawings</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div class="center2">
      <img src="Image.jpg" width="800" height="625" alt="image" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When you say "behind", do you mean around the edges of the image, or that the image is transparent?

Comment: Seems to be working for me in Chrome....

Comment: Note, `//` is not valid in your CSS and can make the styles not load

Comment: Tyler Roper -- yes, around the edges. Theoretically it's "behind" it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could post screen snapshots of your Chrome vs. Firefox images.  Have you cleared your browser cache after making the change to your style sheet and markup?

I did a quick test in Firefox (version 60.0.3) and Chrome (version 70.0.3538.110) and the results look the same to me.  How do these compare to what you expected?

CHROME is on top, FIREFOX is on bottom

[image: Chrome]

[image: Firefox]

Comment: Thanks!!! You're getting the right results.  My Chrome browser gives a grey background color around the image where you see green and dark blue.   Your results tell me that the code is right, and the browser is doing something wrong.  I have the same version of Chrome that you have.    I hate to clear my cache.  I did a 24 hour clear, but that had no effect.

Comment: Okay, now it works.   Maybe clearing the cache did the trick!

Comment: Good on you John.  Yes, when working with browser oddities like you saw, I'm OCD about clear cache/refresh page after every change.  I've seen some browsers hold onto cached styles like a drowning man clinging to the last piece of floating wood ;-)